# How do I compare 2 strings that are not exactly the same in R?

Tags: r

So I would like my code below to return TRUE, even as the front 2 letters are different.

Is there a way to accomplish this? I know == does not work as it compares both exactly.

```
if("UKVICTORIA" == "USVICTORIA") {
  print("TRUE")} else {
    print("FALSE")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `agrepl`

```
> agrepl("UKVICTORIA", "USVICTORIA", max.distance = 1)
[1] TRUE
```

Note, if there is an extra character (`Z`), it returns `FALSE`

```
> agrepl("UZKVICTORIA", "USVICTORIA", max.distance = 1)
[1] FALSE
```

Comment: worth noting that `agrepl("USVICTORIZ", "USVICTORIA", 1)` would also be `TRUE`

Answer (score 0):

Remove first two characters and check the number of unique values.

```
length(unique(sub(".{2}", "", c("UKVICTORIA", "USVICTORIA")))) == 1
#[1] TRUE
```